# File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 998, in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item KeyError: 3327

Tags: python, pandas, keyerror

In below code I am trying to get count of u_count  and h_count, but everytime i get the keyerror

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib
import re
import datetime
pattern = '^(([0-2]?[0-9]/[0-9]?[0-9]/[0-9][0-9]), ([0-9]?[0-9]:[0-9][0-9]\s\w{2}) - (\w+\s\w+|\w+|):( [\w ]+))'
def startsWithDateTime(pattern,s):
    result = re.match(pattern, s)
    if result:
        return True
    return False
def getDataPoint(pattern,s):
    result = re.match(pattern, s)
    date = result[2]
    time = result[3]
    author = result[4]
    message = result[5]
    return date, time, author, message

parsedData = [] # List to keep track of data so it can be used by a Pandas dataframe
conversationPath ="WhatsApp_Chat_with_Umesh.txt" # text file
with open(conversationPath, encoding="utf-8") as fp:
    fp.readline()
    messageBuffer = [] # Buffer to capture intermediate output for multi-line messages
    date, time, author = None, None, None # Intermediate variables to keep track of the current message being processed
    while True:
        line = fp.readline() 
        if not line: # Stop reading further if end of file has been reached
            break
        line = line.strip() # Guarding against erroneous leading and trailing whitespaces
        if startsWithDateTime(pattern,line): # If a line starts with a Date Time pattern, then this indicates the beginning of a new message
            if len(messageBuffer) > 0: # Check if the message buffer contains characters from previous iterations
                parsedData.append([date, time, author, ' '.join(messageBuffer)]) # Save the tokens from the previous message in parsedData
            messageBuffer.clear() # Clear the message buffer so that it can be used for the next message
            date, time, author, message = getDataPoint(pattern,line) # Identify and extract tokens from the line
            messageBuffer.append(message) # Append message to buffer
        else:
            messageBuffer.append(line)


df = pd.DataFrame(parsedData, columns=['Date', 'Time', 'Author', 'Message'])
def count(df):
    df['Letter_count'] = df['Message'].apply(lambda s: len(s))
    df['Word_count'] = df['Message'].apply(lambda s: len(s.split()))

# count(df)
# print(df.head(50))
# print(df['Date'][0])
temp =0
i = 0
h_count= 0
u_count = 0
while True:
    temp = df['Date'][i]
    filter =df[df['Date']==temp]
    data = filter.iloc[0]
        # print(data.loc['Author'])
        # print(type(data))
    if data.loc['Author'] == 'Umesh Yadav':
        u_count +=1
    else:
        h_count +=1
    i =i+1
```

Error Log: (whatsup_env)

> L:\whatsup_chat_analyzer\WhatsApp-Chat-Analyzer> (whatsup_env)
>   L:\whatsup_chat_analyzer\WhatsApp-Chat-Analyzer>C:/Users/Harish/Anaconda3/python.exe
>   l:/whatsup_chat_analyzer/WhatsApp-Chat-Analyzer/analyzer.py Traceback
>   (most recent call last):   File
>   "l:/whatsup_chat_analyzer/WhatsApp-Chat-Analyzer/analyzer.py", line
>   66, in 
>       temp = df['Date'][i]   File "C:\Users\Harish\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py",
>   line 1068, in **getitem**
>       result = self.index.get_value(self, key)   File "C:\Users\Harish\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py",
>   line 4730, in get_value
>       return self._engine.get_value(s, k, tz=getattr(series.dtype, "tz", None))           File "pandas_libs\index.pyx", line 80, in
>   pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_value   File
>   "pandas_libs\index.pyx", line 88, in
>   pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_value   File
>   "pandas_libs\index.pyx", line 131, in
>   pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc    File
>   "pandas_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 992, in
>   pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item   File
>   "pandas_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 998, in
>   pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item KeyError: 3327